# Ios App not receiving message through FCM console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I did every step of FCM Setup Enabled Push notification From capabilities [image]

My Info plist
[image]

I follow every step of Firebase SDK 
put methods which are necessary for App delegate

```
enteclass AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //Slide Menu controller Code
    //Firebase Notification




    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    FirebaseApp.configure()
   let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
     print(" token is  \(String(describing: token))")
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}
//MARK: Token Methods
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("fcm token is \(fcmToken)")
}

//MARK: - Notification Methods
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print(deviceToken)

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
  print(response)
}
```

But still app is not receiving notification from console , Added certificate on firebase. I am also getting token from fcm. I require solution to it, i am very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your device token in Firebase FCM. 
in your delegate method:  `didRegisterForRemoteNotification...`
add following code:

```
Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken;
```

I hope it will work

Comment: r u using development certificate or distribution certificate?

Comment: development certificate and my phone is registered.

Comment: Also pls verify that ur development certificate is added in development section on Firebase Messaging console. (no it Production section)

Comment: Please note that in development mode, Firebase, registering device token is not adding properly sometimes. When you are developing the app, run the twice or thrice to register the token properly. Once it is registered, I am getting push every single time. But in development, you dont need to worry about these issues. It will work from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

For the googlers:

Check `Project file > Your target > Capabilities > Push Notifications` is switched on.
Then check `Project file > Your target > General` and verify that you are signing with a profile that has the push notifications enabled. If not, regenerate the profile and use the new one.

That solved my issue.